# Why and when to user require(bool) on functions

Tags: solidity, remix, require, function

[image: print]

I want to understand when (and why) it's necessary to use this statement :
**require(sent, "failed to send ether")**

i could just do somethink like this instead:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could, but it would not be safe because `call()` won't revert if the external contract execution does. It's highly discouraged and generally unsafe.

Answer (score 1):

With call() if the function reverts your function calling it will not revert unless you have the require(success) line. I've encountered situations where you do not want to revert if the contract you are calling reverts, but most of the time you will want to revert.